# Keep track of customer software release delivery

Tags: release, redmine

I'd like to know if anybody can give me an idea how to keep track of delivered software version(s) to a customer or maybe tell me how others do this?

Say I have a couple of different software binaries each with it's own release versions. Different customers got delivered different versions - for whatever reason. Later on I'd like to know which customer is running which binaries and which versions.

Of course there maybe an approach to simply drop the information into an excel sheet or something like this. But this all depends on the person delivering the software to the customer to keep track of this information.
Ideally I would like to integrate this information into the release/delivery workflow.
We already use a bug tracking system - in our case redmine - but I personally didn't find a working solution which can be combined with the bug tracker. The bug tracking integration is not a requirement. If there is any software based system as described I would prefer a web based system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you mentioned Redmine, here is a workflow that I would use

I would create branches for per-client versions of software on SVN or git I'll assume you use some source code version control system, and a project for each user as a child project in Redmine of some software product, for example with svn:

***Accounting software***   (holds main branch /svn/trunk)
|- Client Bobo (holds /svn/accounting/branches/bobo)
|- Client Koko (holds /svn/accounting/branches/koko)
**CRM software** (/svn/crm/trunk)
|- Client Kiki (/svn/crm/branches/kiki)
|- Client Dudu (/svn/crm/branches/dudu)
|- etc...

This way I would be also able to track bugs on per-client basis, and even be able to have ISSUE-CODE relationship between bugs and particular issues for a particular client!

Best luck! Hope that my answer was helpful!